# Loop with dynamic starting point with condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create this logic that will loop and log custom starting point index base on condition, if current index is not 0 start count will increment

Sample array data:

```
const data = [ 
     { type:'yes',start:1 }, //count index starting point
     { type:'yes',start:1 },
     { type:'no',start:0 }, //skip
     { type:'no',start:0 }, //skip
     { type:'yes',start:5 }, //new index starting point
     { type:'yes',start:5 },
     { type:'no',start:0 },  //skip
     { type:'yes',start:5 }, //new index starting point
     { type:'yes',start:5 },
     { type:'no',start:0 },  //skip
     { type:'yes',start:10 },//new index starting point
     { type:'yes',start:10 },
     { type:'yes',start:10 }, 
]
```

If I run the loop like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
    // code here
    console.log( **newindex** )
}
```

expected **newindex**

```
1,2,0,0,5,6,0,5,6,0,10,11,12
```

Thank you for anyone can help me out

Comment: What is the expected output? `1,2,0,0,5,6,0,5,6,0,10,11,12,13`?

Comment: Why are you doing `console.log()` without any `if` condition?

Comment: I would like to help you but I haven't fully understood your question. Total array items are 13 and out indexes are 14. Could you make it more clear

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather the loop is 13 result not 14 ..but it is dynamic so in can have any 1 or more..

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti yes it is not base on the index of the loop . it is base on start (key as newindex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some kind of external control variable for starting point, here is an example:

```js
const data = [ 
 { type:'yes',start:1 }, //count index starting point
 { type:'yes',start:1 },
 { type:'no',start:0 }, //skip
 { type:'no',start:0 }, //skip
 { type:'yes',start:5 }, //new index starting point
 { type:'yes',start:5 },
 { type:'no',start:0 },  //skip
 { type:'yes',start:5 }, //new index starting point
 { type:'yes',start:5 },
 { type:'no',start:0 },  //skip
 { type:'yes',start:10 },//new index starting point
 { type:'yes',start:10 },
 { type:'yes',start:10 }, 
]

let startingPoint = 0

for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
    if (data[i].start === 0 || startingPoint === 0) {
      startingPoint = data[i].start
    } else {
      startingPoint += 1
      data[i].start = startingPoint
    }
    console.log(data[i].start)
}

//1,2,0,0,5,6,0,5,6,0,10,11,12,13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. It will increase next start index if 2 items are equal:
The output will be `//1,2,0,0,5,6,0,5,6,0,10,11,12`

```js
const data = [ 
   { type:'yes',start:1 }, //count index starting point
   { type:'yes',start:1 },
   { type:'no',start:0 }, //skip
   { type:'no',start:0 }, //skip
   { type:'yes',start:5 }, //new index starting point
   { type:'yes',start:5 },
   { type:'no',start:0 },  //skip
   { type:'yes',start:5 }, //new index starting point
   { type:'yes',start:5 },
   { type:'no',start:0 },  //skip
   { type:'yes',start:10 },//new index starting point
   { type:'yes',start:10 },
   { type:'yes',start:10 }, 
];

let increment = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length -1 ; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].start + increment);
    if (data[i].start !== 0 && data[i].start === data[i+1].start) {
      increment++;
    } else {
      increment = 0;
    }
    if(i === data.length - 2) {console.log(data[data.length-1].start + increment);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use map and a loop

```js
const dataxd = [ { type:'yes',start:1 }, { type:'yes',start:1 }, { type:'no',start:0 }, { type:'no',start:0 }, { type:'yes',start:5 }, { type:'yes',start:5 }, { type:'no',start:0 }, { type:'yes',start:5 }, { type:'yes',start:5 }, { type:'no',start:0 }, { type:'yes',start:10 }, { type:'yes',start:10 }, { type:'yes',start:10 }, ]
 ns=dataxd.map(o=>o.start)
 counter=1
 for (let i=0;i<ns.length;i++){
    if(ns[i]==0) {counter=1;continue}
    else if(ns[i-1]!=0 && i!=0) ns[i]= ns[i]+counter,counter++  
 }
 console.log(ns)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [ 
   { type:'yes',start:1 }, //count index starting point
   { type:'yes',start:1 },
   { type:'no',start:0 }, //skip
   { type:'no',start:0 }, //skip
   { type:'yes',start:5 }, //new index starting point
   { type:'yes',start:5 },
   { type:'no',start:0 },  //skip
   { type:'yes',start:5 }, //new index starting point
   { type:'yes',start:5 },
   { type:'no',start:0 },  //skip
   { type:'yes',start:10 },//new index starting point
   { type:'yes',start:10 },
   { type:'yes',start:10 }, 
];

let index = 0;
let counter = 0;

let result = data.map((obj) => {
  if (obj['start'] !== 0) { // If start value is 0, goto else block
    if (index !== +obj['start']) { // If start value changes
      index = +obj['start']; // Save start value into index
      counter = +obj['start']; // Save start value into counter
      return obj; // return for first time
    }
    counter += 1; // From second time onwards : Add 1 to saved start value
    obj['start'] = counter; // Update start
    return obj; // Now return the object
  } else {
    index = 0; // Reset index to 0
    return obj; // Return same object
  }
});

console.log(result);
```